# Error:non-zero exit value 2

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin

I have added a jar file named ' `http component-client` ' in my project and it was downloaded and gradle was build successfully but whenever I try to make the apk or run the project it gives me an error as:

> com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException:
>   org.gradle.process.internal.ExecException: Process 'command
>   'C:\Program Files(x86)\Java\jdk1.7.0\bin\java.exe'' finished with
>   non-zero exit value 2

So please tell me how to remove it

Comment: What does that JAR do and why do you need it? If you remove it, what'll happen?

Comment: It is used for http client connection actually I want to parse some text fields from MySQL server to android textviews so I saw an example over the internet which does the same thing then I edited my project as there was written and I had to download this jar

Comment: it's probably conflicting with something. What do your gradle dependencies look like? Are you using multidex?

Comment: No I thought of it after seeing stack overflow on same type of question but I could not because I was not able to extend Application class

Comment: You probably saw a Multidex post and that isn't needed for your problem. You seem to be adding Apache HTTP client, which is deprecated. You don't need any external libraries do use HTTP requests to talk to PHP (?) that connects to MySQL

Comment: Ok I will see it and try to execute this without any library and could you provide me any example of publishing the texts from MySQL to android text view as I am not sure how to do this thanks pls reply